# Scripting Help Needed

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I need help writing a script.

The requirements are:

A script that takes an absolute reference to a file or directory (/tmp/somefile or /home/username/somefile) as an argument and displays the following:

1. Is the file a file or a directory?
2. Do I have read access to the file/directory?
3. Do I have write access to the file/directory?
4. Is the file executable?
5. The permissions on the file - the rwx stuff out of "ls -l" will work.

If you have any good resources which I can read please feel free to post them, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ls -l` not good enough? The output contains all that information...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here address a _specific programming problem_. Simply asking for code without demonstrating effort is frowned upon. Add some code to your question and show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shown what you've tried so far, I'll refrain from giving you a direct answer (simply because I don't know if this is homework or if you just haven't tried).

You will find the ["Conditional Expressions"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) section in the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) useful.

For example, under the list of test commands:

> ```
> -r file
>       True if file exists and is readable.
> ```

Applying that in an `if` statement:

```
[me@home]$ if [ -r $HOME ]; then echo "readable"; else echo "not readable"; fi
readable
[me@home]$ if [ -r /root ]; then echo "readable"; else echo "not readable"; fi
not readable
```

This should answer your second question, i.e. "Do I have read access to the file/directory?".

There are similar flags to test for "is a directory", "is writeable", "is executable", etc. which answers most of your other questions (apart from the last question).

For your last question, here's one way to extract the permissions column from `ls -l`:

```
[me@home]$ ls -l $HOME/.bashrc | awk '{print $1}'
-rw-r--r--
```

Good luck with your script.